# decreasing false positive rate at regions of high true positive rate

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have an optimized deep dense neural network in keras for a binary classification problem. I want to reduce the false positive rate at regions of high true positive rate. In other words I want to get as many of the true positive signals as possible (about 80%) and reduce the false positive rate. The situation is very similar to what is described in this paper except the network that I am using is more complicated with 5 layers and as many as 200 nodes in the first layer:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/YihGoodmanHulten-ceas06.pdf
I've tried many different approaches including two staged training, biasing the loss function, and modifying the weights of the samples in various ways. However, the end result has always been either no change in the roc curves or an increase in the false positive rate in the regions of low true positive rate (roughly around 20%)

Is there any way for me to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: This is a good topic, but your posting isn't nearly specific enough to elicit useful answers.

Comment: Could you specify what further information would be helpful? thanks.

Comment: @Prune: ping from aniromi's comment